# making ajax calls to asp.net webservice using jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery, web-services, jquery-mobile

I have webservice up and live. When I make calls to it via jquery using my asp.net application it works fine, but using jquery mobile I get a 500 error message with no results. I am not sure why this is happening. if anyone would have any knowledge of this please let me know. Thanks.

EDIT: I just noticed that my request says Request Method:OPTIONS.

Javascript

```
  var parameter = {
                    'userName': emailLogin, 'password': passwordLogin
                };
                parameter = JSON.stringify(parameter);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://myurl.com/MainService.asmx/LoginMobile",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    data: parameter,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (result) {
                        if(result.d) {
                            showErrorDialogMessage('Login error', result.d);
                        } else {
                            showErrorDialogMessage('Login error', 'Incorrect email and password combination.');
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        showErrorDialogMessage('Login error', textStatus);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed datatype to  "jsonp" and was able to make the call and retrieve the data base in xml data.